# Change display on js

Tags: javascript, css, variables, display

Can someone explain me whats wrong with this and why is it not working?

```
var firstdiv = document.getElementById("firstdiv");
var secdiv = document.getElementById("seconddiv");
var thidiv = document.getElementById("thirddive");
var foudiv = document.getElementById("fourthdiv");

function btnforfirst() {
    if (firstdiv = "none") {
        firstdiv.style.display = "block";
      secdiv.style.display = "none";
      thidiv.style.display = "none";
      foudiv.style.display = "none";
    }
```

But when i do this it works:

```
function btnforfirst() {
        if (firstdiv = "none") {
            document.getElementById("firstdiv").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("seconddiv").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("thirddiv").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("fourthdiv").style.display = "none";
        }
```

Where and what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: A few things. First of all, please explain what you are trying to accomplish with this code snippet. Second, you are assigning the value `none` to the `firstdiv` variable with `firstdiv = "none"`. You need to use equals operator (`==`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot another closing curly bracket at the end also, you need to put the value for the if statement to null instead of "none"

```
let firstdiv = document.getElementById("firstdiv");
let secdiv = document.getElementById("seconddiv");
let thidiv = document.getElementById("thirddive");
var foudiv = document.getElementById("fourthdiv");

function btnforfirst() {
       if(firstdiv == null) {
          firstdiv.style.display = "block";
          seconddiv.style.display = "none";
          thirddiv.style.display = "none";
          fourthdiv.style.display = "none";
       }
}
```